# Custom layout weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-framelayout

I have created a custom framelayout that contains multiple views inside it. When the layout is clicked, some animations are done inside the layout. I have created two instances of the layout in my XML as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.MyProj
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.example.MyProj>

    <com.example.MyProj
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </com.example.MyProj>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the weird behavior here is that, after defining these layouts in my main class, when I click on the first layout, animation is happening on the second layout ie, when i click on frame1, frame 2 is animating. The second layout is responding fine when clicked. So the layout which is defined the latest is getting animated. The layout which got defined first is not getting animated.

[image: Layouts in main xml]

This is how I have defined the layouts in my main class:

```
    final MyProj fl = (MyProj) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
    final MyProj fl1 = (MyProj) findViewById(R.id.frame2);

    fl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            fl.reset();
            fl.animation();
        }
    });

    fl1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            fl.reset();
            fl1.animation();
        }
    });
```

Could someone please explain why these layouts are behaving in this way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post code of com.example.MyProj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Making all my variables static created the problem.Reverting them to private cleared the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check your code here:

```
fl1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fl.reset();
        fl1.animation();
    }
});
```

it should be:
      fl1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fl1.reset();
        fl1.animation();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem here is, no matter what i write inside the onclicklistener, it will animate the latest created layout in my xml.

Comment: Then the problem is in your animation() method

Comment: animation methhod is wroking properly. It is just that the animation is happening on the latest instance of the class. For example if I create only one instance of the layout class and when i click on it, it is animating properly. But when I create multiple instances, no matter whichever instance i click, only the last defined instance will animate.